# Fundamental group of the crown with quotient?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am studying now the Seifert-Van-Kampen's theorem and I am trying to find some other examples than torus, Klein bottle, etc... that seem easy with this theorem.

I had an example of a quotient space which is the circular crown with the quotient that identifies antipodal points in each circle.

I've been trying to find a partition in this space to aply the theorem in a similar way of torus and klein bottle but I don't know what are the fundamental groups of the spaces I get.

Is there any way to find this fundamental group with this theorem?

Comment: Could you define your space more precisely ? It is an annulus, quotiented by antipodal action on each circle ?

Comment: Yes, in each (internal and external) border circle antipodal points are identified.

Comment: If you take "thick neighborhood" of each circle which intersect along an annulus, the intersection is a normal annulus thus $U_1 \cap U_2 \cong S^1 \times [0,1]$. Each $U_i$ is a Moebius band which has also $\mathbb Z$ as fundamental group. I think you should be able to compute the fundamental group with this !

Comment: Thank you! I just have to calculate the free product with amalgamation of these spaces, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly !!